# Fastest way to preview all images in a deeply nested directory tree?

Tags: finder, photos.app, preview

I have a set of hundreds of images and each one is in its own sub-directory. What is the fastest way to preview all images at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

From terminal app:

```
find . -iname '*.png' | xargs open
```